# Uncaught ReferenceError: is_dir is not defined

Tags: javascript, jsvalidation

I am getting this error when I was trying to use validate the path whether the the path given by the user is valid or not?

[Please click here to view image code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjLyI.png)

Comment: Post the code itself. Screenshot doesn't help.

Comment: Post your problem along with the code into this post, not as an image. That is incredibly annoying. is_dir is not a valid js function, and you're not implementing it here yourself either. That's why it's not defined. is_dir is a php function, maybe you're confusing the two

Answer (score 0):

From where exactly comes `is_dir` function?

Seems like you are calling the function before defining it. If you are sure that it is defined in "somewhere" tries to execute your code after page loaded:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function (event) {
  // Your code goes here.
});
```